Twilio Studio Flow and Send and Wait for Reply Widget Both Triggering on Incoming
I have a Twilio Studio Flow that is triggered through the REST API. Within the flow, I use a "Send and Wait for Reply" widget to wait for a user's response.
The issue I'm encountering is that when the user replies, both the "Send and Wait for Reply" widget and the entire Studio Flow are triggered by the new incoming message/conversation. This leads to the flow being triggered again instead of handling the reply within the existing session.
Here's a summary of my setup:

I trigger the Twilio Studio Flow via REST API.
The flow contains a "Send and Wait for Reply" widget.
When a user replies, both the "Send and Wait for Reply" widget and the entire Studio Flow are triggered by the new incoming message/conversation.

I expected that once the "Send and Wait for Reply" widget is active, the user's reply would be handled within the same session and not trigger the entire flow again.
Has anyone experienced this issue or have any insights on how to ensure that replies are handled correctly within the active session without re-triggering the entire flow?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

My Send and Wait for widget is working fine but the whole studio is also getting triggered with that incoming message

It happens because probably your phone number trigger a studio flow when receives a message, so when you trigger the flow via API, when user answer the message Twilio will check if already exists an conversation to this user and if no it'll create a new one and will add a conversation webhook to this conversation that will trigger the flow configured.
I had conflict to trigger flows via API as you, now I prefer create a new conversation and add a webhook to trigger this conversation for example when a new message is add to it.
Follow an example:
//creating a new conversation 
const newConversation = await client.conversations.v1.conversations.create({
      friendlyName: `${conversation.friendlyName} - Survey Conversation`,
      attributes: JSON.stringify({ originalConversationSid: conversation.sid }),
});

//adding a whatsapp customer to conversation
await newConversation.participants().create({
      messagingBinding: {
        address: filterCustomer.messagingBinding.address,
        proxyAddress: filterCustomer.messagingBinding.proxy_address,
      },
});

//adding a conversation webhook that will trigger a specific flow based on SID, and the filter "onMessageAdded" and the replayAfter "0" mean that when the first message is added on conversation it'll trigger the flow specified
const webhook = await newConversation.webhooks().create({
      target: 'studio',
      configuration: {
        filters: 'onMessageAdded',
        flowSid: TWILIO_SURVEY_FLOW_SID,
        replayAfter: 0,
      },
});

//forcing to initialize the flow by our function, the important here is the "xTwilioWebhookEnabled" it means that our message will trigger the webhook, without it, the message post by api not will trigger the webhook added above
await newConversation.messages().create({
      author: filterCustomer.messagingBinding.address,
      body: 'Flow initializing...',
      xTwilioWebhookEnabled: 'true',
});


If you cannot use the example above, you can try to track the user to check if it has an active conversation, for example, when you trigger the flow via API, you create a conversation for it, and when you receive an answer you can check if this user already has an active conversation and ignore the trigger coming from the incoming message.
I hope that it can help you!

Thanks for explaining the root cause . I understood the root cause of this but didn't fully understand what exactly needed to be done. Should I create the conversation and check whether it exists in a Twilio function, then add it to the Studio Flow?

If you can create a conversation before start the Studio Flow, I think that the best option is, create the conversation and add a Studio Webhook to conversation, as I show on the answer, with it you can initialize your studio flow without need to use the Studio API, you'll just use the conversations API
